# Under what circumstances should it be designed as an iterator

Tags: design-patterns

Under what circumstances should it be designed as an iterator.

I have a Polygon class whose attributes are aggregated by edges. Should I directly use an edge array as its member, or design Polygon as an iterator of the edge collection? Can I get some suggestions, and what are the reasons for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define Polygon as a "regular" class, exposing a read-only collection of Edges. It's more generic and reusable.
That collection can be typed (eg. `EdgesCollection` or whatever), and expose some convenience methods on it.